# pycharm django debug configrations doesn't recognize apps folder

Tags: django, pycharm

All my apps are in `apps` folder

I also added `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apps"))`
in settings.py

my project structure as below:

[image]

But when I simply create and run a default Django Server in Pycharm (2019.1)
[image]

It returned an error

```
...  'apps' is not a package
```

My project runs perfectly in `pipenv shell; python manage.py runserver`
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out it's due to the `Content Root` setting

My Git root is `dwhnt` but my Django root is `dwhnt/proj`
After deleting the old Content Root and set it with as below it works

[image]